# I have problem while opening terminal

Tags: bash

When I try to open a Terminal, it shows me this error:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal.
getpt failed: No such file or directory.
```

with these two buttons:

1. profile preferences
2. relaunch

Comment: please take a screenshot of that terminal and then upload it to imgur.com.Finally provide the uploaded link here.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is in your **fstab** file , try to fix the problem in it.

Backup your fstab :

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
```

Add this line at the end your fstab :

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

add this line at the end :

```
devpts                  /dev/pts        devpts           rw             0 0
```

Comment: I don't have that in my system. Why you think he needs it?

Comment: I agree with Braiam, messing around with fstab (and not even suggesting to backup it before) is really dangerous.

Comment: how he will run the commands.. problem in opening terminal itself..